# Install resolution

Tags: system-installation, resolution

I'm trying to install Elementary one a spare computer that I'm going to give to my nephew - I don't have a monitor but the computer has an HDMI input so I plug it into my television and try install it, for some reason the install screen just blows up my resolution, normally I can see the entire install screen but when I use elementary I only see the top 25% of my screen blown up huge. I've tried two different USB pen drives - downloaded the ISO two different times, and it still happens has anyone seen this occur - any solutions?

Comment: Did you try to change resolution from the display plug?

Comment: Perhaps your TV resolution is wrong or  inadequate. Try changing it in TV config. Otherwise you can try to boot USB installer, edit grub line and force a fine resolution.

Comment: No because when I try to install Linux mint or another version of Linux resolution is perfect. I was just set on using elementary OS.

Comment: Have you tried the second option bitseater mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that problem too. I solved it that way:

In `/boot/`open configuration file and uncomment `disable_overscan=1` (if this parameter is 0 then set it to 1).

Below you have `overscan_left`, `overscan_right`, `overscan_top` and `overscan_bottom`. Changing values of these parameters you can adjust your display to TV.

After setting everything, save and close document (you need to be in sudo mode) and restart your computer.

Now you can see if system is displayed properly. If not then try changing values for left, right, top and bottom parameters. :)

Answer (score -1):

well here is a solution you might try,get a hdmi adapter and convert the hdmi out on your pc to a VGA signal then select VGA input on the tv and everything should be fine

Comment: Not all TVs have VGA...